# Help identifying this animal

Tags: animal-identification, wilderness, night, monkeys

Anyone can help me identify this animal? It walks like a cat and climbs trees like a monkey. No tail is visible in the video. This video was captured in Arunachal Pradesh, a provincial state in the north Eastern region of India (Asia), during night time. Image is attached (Not very clear though).

Video link - https://youtube.com/shorts/jnIQxU79m7Q?feature=share

[image]

Comment: How close to sunset/sunrise? Quite a lot of species are active near dawn and dusk.  I need to look in the book I have at home, but I'm not thinking monkey

Comment: I'm thinking [mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose) but I have never seen one.

Comment: Please see the video in the link. It seems more like a wild cat family.

Comment: I watched the video. Another suggestion: [loris](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=loris&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X).

Comment: I'm thinking [slow loris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_loris)

Comment: @WeatherVane I have, in India, and I agree from the photo, though the [species I saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruddy_mongoose) (Wikipedia link, 2nd photo is mine).  The face looks shorter in the video, but the youtube shorts interface is so utterly stupid (no rewind, no dragging a progress bar, pause is slow to react) that I can't get a good look at it.  Why on earth did they produce something so useless - and why does anyone use it?

Comment: The slow loris (which I've only seen in zoos) has a dark stripe down the back, and it does show in the video

Comment: @bob1 after watching the video repeatedly, I'm with you on that

Comment: You might find it more profitable to ask people from the local tribes or older people who have lived there a long time. That region of India has a lot of fauna.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Bengal slow loris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengal_slow_loris) is found in the extreme north east of India, including Arunachal Pradesh.  Most of the slow lorises are found further east.

I've seen other slow loris species in zoos, and the eye-shine from the big eyes is good, the movement is good, and the size (as best I can guess from where it's climbing) is good.  Two major identifying features are the lack of a tail (they have a vestigial tail and the dark stripe down the back, visible at one point in the video.  The face is too short for mongoose species, and that deliberate climbing along narrow things isn't good for mongooses either.  Similarly slow lorises are properly nocturnal, while mongooses are diurnal/crepuscular.

According to Prater *The Book of Indian Animals*, we should also look out for dark circles around the eyes (masked by the eye-shine in the video).  I would expect the nearby habitat to be dense forest.  Slow lorises can apparently be tamed and kept as pets, so it's possible the one you saw was an escape, especially if the habitat is wrong.  If it's truly wild you were lucky to see it at all.

Comment: BTW lemurs are primates, related to monkeys, but not monkeys.  So I wasn't completely wrong in my initial comment